# JavaScript inheritance mechanism

Tags: javascript, inheritance

Im learning JS inheritance right now, and there's something unclear to me.
Consider the following code:

```
function Mammal(pName){
    var name = pName; //"private" variable name
    this.getName = function(){ //return name via closure
        return name;
    }
    this.mammalStuff = function(){
        console.log("im a mammal!!");
    }
}
Mammal.prototype.speak = function(){
    console.log("im a "+ this.getName()+" !")  //every Mammal can speak
}

function Cat(){
    this.catStuff = function(){
        console.log("cat says mew");
    }
}

Cat.prototype = new Mammal(); //All cat objects inherit all Mammal characteristics

var houseCat = new Cat("Kittie");
```

Now, `houseCat` can access the `mammalStuff` and `catStuff` properties. Right now in the current code configuration, `houseCat` prints `undefined` whenever I call the `getName` \ `speak` methods. Why cant I directly use the Parent class constructor for the `name` attribute?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you ask for a property on a JS object, JS will traverse the prototype chain until it finds that property. So objects inherit from their prototypes.

A constructor is just a function. When a function (constructor of Cat) is executed, there is no rule for also invoking other functions (constructor of Mammal).

You can force this to happen explicitely. e.g.

```
function Cat(name){
    Mammal.call(this, name);
    this.catStuff = function(){
        console.log("cat says mew");
    }
}
```

Comment: `Mammal.call(this, name);` acts like the `super` keyword in Java for instance?

Comment: @undroid, that's a way of looking at it. You have to be careful through, if you hadn't done `Cat.prototype = new Mammal()` then calling `Mammal.call(this, name);` could try to call functions that don't exist on `this`.

Comment: What is the best practice in this case? Add the `name` constructor to the `Cat` function, or to use the `Mammal`s  `getName` via the `call` method?

Comment: Mozilla has a good reference example: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/create#Example:_Classical_inheritance_with_Object.create

Answer (score 1):

There is no "parent class". There are no classes in JavaScript. Constructors are not inherited, only attributes are.

EDIT in response to comment: There are no classes. :) You set the `Cat`'s prototype to be `new Mammal()`, which is equivalent to `new Mammal(undefined)`. Thus, when you call `getName()`, you are calling `getName` on the prototype, and in that closure, `name` is `undefined`.

Comment: This means every "class" must have its own constructor?

Answer (score 1):

`Cat` does not inherit the `Mammal`'s constructor. Thus, `name` variable is undefined in your case.

Answer (score 0):

Getting inheritance right in javascript is hard, you need to take care of both the prototype and its constructor property if you want `instanceof` and some other things to work.

Have a look at [this MDN article](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Introduction_to_Object-Oriented_JavaScript#Inheritance) describing how it's done properly